# Athena/Trino/Presto code to parse text file with custom line separator

Tags: amazon-athena, presto, text-processing, trino

I want to parse some log files in plain text file with records spanning across multiple lines using Trino/Presto code. My data looks like this: each record has multiple lines and each line has a variable. Each record is separated by --------------. I want to parse the record and save in parquet format, so each record in a row and every variable in a column.

```
-----------------------
var1=abcde/n
var2=12345/n
....
varn=xxxx/n
-----------------------
var1=defg/n
var2=78910/n
....
varn=yyyy/n
```

Desired output:

```
var1, var2 ...  varn
------------------------------
abcde 12345 ... xxx
defg  78910 ... xxx
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like a good task for SQL even for Trino. There are many scripting options out there that can do that easier.

Comment: @Guy, thanks for your comments, can you suggest some options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL, including its extensions in [Trino](https://trino.io/) and [Presto](https://prestodb.io/), is designed primarily for operating on structured data in tabular format. Parsing unstructured, multi-line text files is outside the typical use case for SQL, and while it might be possible, it would likely require complex and hard-to-maintain code. And Trino or Presto may not have built-in functions to handle custom line separators or multi-line records easily.

Or: Frameworks like [Apache Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/) or [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) are designed for processing large datasets and can handle unstructured data. Spark, in particular, has powerful capabilities for working with text data and can write to Parquet format easily.

You also have [ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) like [Apache NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/) that are designed for data transformation tasks. These tools often provide graphical interfaces for defining data transformations, and can handle complex parsing tasks.

---

For example, consider a Python script that uses the `pandas` library (`pip install pandas pyarrow`) to parse your log files and save the parsed data to a Parquet file. I will assume that the `/n` in your data is a typo and that it should actually be `\n` to indicate a new line:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Function to parse the log file
def parse_log_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
    # Split the content by the record separator
    records = content.split('-----------------------')[1:-1]  # Exclude the first and last element which are empty
    # Parse each record into a dictionary
    parsed_records = []
    for record in records:
        lines = record.strip().split('\n')
        record_dict = {line.split('=')[0]: line.split('=')[1] for line in lines if line}
        parsed_records.append(record_dict)
    return parsed_records

# Call the function and convert the result to a DataFrame
log_data = parse_log_file('your_log_file.txt')
df = pd.DataFrame(log_data)

# Save the DataFrame to a Parquet file
df.to_parquet('parsed_data.parquet', index=False)
```

The function `parse_log_file` that reads the log file, splits the content by the record separator (`-----------------------`), and parses each record into a dictionary. The list of dictionaries is converted to a DataFrame using [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), which is then saved to a Parquet file using the [`to_parquet` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet).

That would work for the data format you provided, as long as said data is *consistently* formatted.
If there are variations in the data format,... you may need to modify the parsing logic.